# how can i use navigation bar with navigation graph in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigationbar

I'm using a navigation graph and navigation bar in a project and I want to use host nav on one of the bottoms. but the code doesn't work. actually when I import androidx.navigation.Navigation to fragments that makes an app crash. how can id fix this?
in here I write how to change fragment and witch part of code make the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnFsY.png)error.

```
// The part of code that makes error
navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.id_postBtn).setOnClickListener(this)



// how i change fragment
private fun replaceFrag(frag: Fragment){
        val fragTran = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragTran.replace(R.id.container, frag)
        fragTran.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **navigation graph** you have to set an action under source fragment. like :

```
<action
     android:id="@+id/search_action"
     app:destination="@+id/destinationFragmentId" />
```

Here it is important of **id** of **action** tag.
Now in source fragment you have to change your button click listener like `yourButton.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.search_action));`

> Look here id is the same id of action tag.

And no need to replace fragment or commit fragment. All will take care of your navigation graph. First design correct map in your navigation graph.

For more information you can visit [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)